# Append Search div as first nav list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have search controls which show up in mobile version when user click the menu bav button.
Search controls are wrapped inside following div
`<div class="search-nav-w">...</div>`

and my menu structure is like below

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <div id="menu-button" class="menu-opened"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/news/">News</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I want my menu structure to append search div to ul nav so that my HTML will be like this

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <div id="menu-button" class="menu-opened"></div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="search-nav-w">...</div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/news/">News</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I amusing following jquery but it doent work for me

```
$("#cssmenu > ul").append("<li>"+$(".search-nav-w")+"</li>");
```

**UPDATED**
I tried prepend and append but my it show my list item as `<li>[object Object]</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**prependTo**](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/) to move, and `wrap` to wrap the element in other element.

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the beginning of the target.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/87yzqdrr/)

```
$(".search-nav-w").wrap('<li id="search"></li>');
$('#search').prependTo($("#cssmenu > ul"));
```

Comment: I tried prepend and append but my it show my list item as `<li>[object Object]</li>`

Comment: I want to wrap it around `<li>..</li>`

Comment: It behavies like `$(".search-nav-w").prependTo($("#cssmenu > ul"));` without wrapping around list

Comment: @Tusshar, Thanks man. i think this is the way to do, But i am still not sure what it doenst work the way i tried and teh way you tried with `wrap()`. I will mark your answer correct since it server my purpose. Happy diwali man

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking to add an input field.

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<div id="menu-button" class="menu-opened"></div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/news/">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var _serachMenu =$("<li><div class='search-nav-w'></div></li>")
$("#cssmenu > ul").prepend(_serachMenu);
```

CSS for testing the existence of div

```
.search-nav-w{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
   border:1px solid red;

}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lvmc4dg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You are prepending `$(".search-nav-w")` not as an object, but as an [HTMLstring](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString) (which shows it as `[object Object]`).
Try using:

```
$("#cssmenu > ul").prepend('<li><div class="search-nav-w"></div></li>');
```

Comment: what about controls inside div `$("#cssmenu > ul").append("<li>"+$(".search-nav-w")+"</li>");`

Comment: You can't use selectors  inside the append/prepend method, it will output is as a string like you descovered. You only can use a selector when the element which you want to append is already inside the DOM. 
http://jsfiddle.net/5coxve18/2/